# AppSync with multiple Cognito User Pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am working on an Amplify application with AppSync GraphQL as API.

I am trying to have 2 separate user pools that can be used as authentication sources for this GraphQL API.

Following the Amplify tutorial, I was able to deploy the AppSync GraphQL API, but there is no option for me to configure multiple user pools.

I looked into the AWS Console and saw that I can add more User Pools under "Additional authorization providers", but when I did then tried it out in Query section, only the first User Pool works. The API responded with

```
"message": "Not Authorized to access listTodos on type Query"
```

Here is my schema:

```
type Todo @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}
```

I also tried to add the second User Pools as Authentication Provider for the Identity Pool generated by Amplify, no luck as well.

Is it possible to use 2 User Pools in a single AppSync API? What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem but. Finally I figured it out.

you have to add extra directives to your schema with multiple authorizations. In your case, you should update your schema as follows:

```
type Todo @model @aws_cognito_user_pools {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}
```

You can find more information about this from here: 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/

Comment: As far as I can see, this answer is about using multiple types (e.g. cognito and IAM). the question is about using just cognito but having multiple pools

Comment: It seems like adding `@aws_cognito_user_pools` authorizes all configured user pools. Without this directive, only the default authorization (potentially only the first user pool) gets access.